# Difference Between Expanded and LayoutSize.Expand for Column and Row in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I was trying Jetpack Compose on Android Studio Canary 1 and I added `Column` composable to the ui. `Column` has one property called `modifier` in which we can pass different modifiers. I used `Expanded` modifier which resulted in `Column` taking all the available space.

Also, `Column` has `mainAxisSize` and `crossAxisSize` properties so I tried them also and set it to `LayoutSize.Expand` which is intended to expand the given axis I think. This also resulted in `Column` taking all the available space. Check out the example below:

### 1. Using LayoutSize.Expand

```
Column(mainAxisSize = LayoutSize.Expand,
crossAxisSize = LayoutSize.Expand) {
    Text("Jetpack",modifier = ExpandedHeight)
    Text("Compose",modifier = ExpandedHeight)
}
```

#### Output:

[image]

### 2. Using Expanded

```
Column(modifier = Expanded) {
    Text("Jetpack",modifier = ExpandedHeight)
    Text("Compose",modifier = ExpandedHeight)
}
```

#### Output:

[image]

> Observation is that Both the following code provides the same output.
>   Then what is the difference between `Expanded` and `LayoutSize.Expand`
>   when it comes to `Column` and `Row`?

Comment: Check this [commit](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/f5f1fda0af88bbf5e26d2605ed2b3dc14d73f81d).  `mainAxisSize` parameter was removed from `Row`/`Column`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are two ways to achieve the same thing:

The [Expanded modifier](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-master-dev/ui/ui-layout/src/main/java/androidx/ui/layout/ExpandedModifier.kt?autodive=0%2F#53) forces a target component to fill all available space. It can be applied to any composable that accepts a modifier.

The mainAxisSize parameter is a way to set the size of the layout, and is a parameter that is specific to Row/Column.

You should use the Expanded modifier. The mainAxisSize parameter is already removed from [Column](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-master-dev/ui/ui-layout/src/main/java/androidx/ui/layout/Flex.kt?autodive=0%2F#245).

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/Modifier

Answer (score 3):

On jetpack compose 1.0,  Expanded modifier which looks like flutter api is no longer available
But you can do it like this.

```kotlin
Row {
    Box(modifier = 
      Modifier.weight(1f).wrapContentWidth(Alignment.Start)) {}
    Box() {}
}
```

In the first Box composable, the layout is expanded. It's similar to flutter Flex widget if you familiar with flutter.

You can also view the google ref here https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/intrinsic-measurements